# How do I install Docker on an NVIDIA Tegra Jetson TK1 with a 32 bit ARM processor running Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: arm, docker, gpu, dockerhub, jupyter

Docker only supports 64 bit x86 Linux, but people have made images for the Raspberry Pi with a 32 bit ARM processor.  Will these work with the TK1?  I am new to Docker.  I am trying to put Jupyterhub on my TK1 to take advantage of the GPU via Gnumpy package for Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am trying to achieve something similar to your goal. However, I am "Work in Progress", so I will try to give my best, and I will come later to make some edits if needed.

First of all, there is a `docker.io` package (the official Docker package on Ubuntu distributions) at ports.ubuntu.com (which is the default on the Jetson Tegra K1). This means that you can `apt-get install docker.io`, but it won't work because the kernel is not ready for it.

I have heard that the kernel is quite limited, but fortunately there is a guy at the developer zone who has prepared some nice kernel:
https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/823132/-customkernel-the-grinch-21-3-3-for-jetson-tk1-developed/

For the last version (yesterday: 26 April 2015) there is an interesting thing:

```
 Added Docker support: POSIX_MQUEUE, CGROUP_PERF, CFS_BANDWIDTH
```

... which should enable the `docker`. I have yet to test this last version, I plan to do it soon.

Comment: Thanks, I want to upgrade to the latest Grinch kernel, but my micro USB port came off.  I destroyed it trying to solder it back on, so I am waiting for replacement ports.  I'm not really that good at surface mounts.  I wish NVIDIA would have used a full sized USB port.

Comment: Did you have any success with docker on Jetson, @MariusSiuram?

Comment: @berezovskiy I did some tests, but the problems with the ARM images (little support for them, lack of ecosystem) seemed too much work. Moreover, adding support for CUDA to the images seemed an extra challenge on top of that, so I ended abandoning my initial idea